# Find & Delete Duplicate Records on All Tables in current MSSQL Database

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedure

The purpose of this code is to search the entire database for duplicate records and produce a script that a user could then run to delete all of the duplicates.

The stored procedure takes the following parameters:

**`@DiscludeTables varchar(max)`**:  a string of Table Names separated by semicolons.  These tables are not included in the search for duplicate records and therefore will not be affected in any way by the resulting script when it is run.

**`@DiscludeColumns varchar(max)`**: a string of Column Names separated by semicolons.  These columns are not used to determine whether records are duplicates or not.  Including any column here will effectively identify that records can have varying information within this column and still be identified as a duplicate.

**`@Output varchar(max)`**: this is the string that the output will be passed to.

The output string defines the use database, a cte of duplicates and delete statement for each table in the database.

I've just started to get my hands dirty with SQL and could use some enlightenment on how to improve this script in any way.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_getDatabaseWideDuplicateDeleteScript] (@DiscludeTables varchar(max), @DiscludeColumns varchar(max), @Output varchar(max) output )
AS


--START SETUP DISCLUDE TABLES AND DISCLUDE COLUMNS
--***************************************************
--this section basically just splits the strings @discludetables and @discludecolumns by ';' occurance
-- and sticks the resulting strings in to tables @@discludecolumns and @@discludeTables
--Debug Variables
--DECLARE @DiscludeTables varchar(max)
--SET @DiscludeTables = '__MigrationHistory'
--DECLARE @DiscludeColumns varchar(max)
--SET @DiscludeColumns = 'Name'
--DECLARE @Output varchar(max)

DECLARE @pos INT
DECLARE @string varchar(max)
DECLARE @@DiscludeTables TABLE
(
    tableName varchar(max)
)

DECLARE @@DiscludeColumns TABLE
(
    columnName varchar(max)
)

DECLARE @stringToSplit varchar(max)
SET @stringToSplit = @DiscludeTables

WHILE CHARINDEX(';', @stringToSplit) > 0
BEGIN
    SELECT @pos  = CHARINDEX(';', @stringToSplit)  
    SELECT @string = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, 1, @pos-1)

    INSERT INTO @@DiscludeTables 
    SELECT @string

    SELECT @stringToSplit = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, @pos+1, LEN(@stringToSplit)-@pos)
END
IF @stringToSplit IS NOT NULL AND @stringToSplit != ''
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @@DiscludeTables
    SELECT @stringToSplit
END



SET @stringToSplit = @DiscludeColumns

WHILE CHARINDEX(';', @stringToSplit) > 0
BEGIN
    SELECT @pos  = CHARINDEX(';', @stringToSplit)  
    SELECT @string = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, 1, @pos-1)

    INSERT INTO @@DiscludeColumns
    SELECT @string

    SELECT @stringToSplit = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, @pos+1, LEN(@stringToSplit)-@pos)
END
IF @stringToSplit IS NOT NULL AND @stringToSplit != ''
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @@DiscludeColumns
    SELECT @stringToSplit
END


SET @Output = ''
DECLARE @DBName varchar(max)
SET @DBName = DB_NAME()

SELECT * FROM @@DiscludeColumns
SELECT * FROM @@DiscludeTables



--**********************************************
--END SETUP DISCLUDE TABLES AND DISCLUDE COLUMNS



--LOOP THROUGH ALL TABLES IN DATABASE NOT IN DISCLUDE TABLES
--***********************************
DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(256), @ColumnName nvarchar(128)
SET  @TableName = ''
WHILE @TableName IS NOT NULL
BEGIN

    --GET THE CURRENT TABLE
    SET @TableName = 

        (
        SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME))
        FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
        WHERE       TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
            AND QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) > @TableName
            AND OBJECTPROPERTY(
                    OBJECT_ID(
                        QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)
                    ), 'IsMSShipped'
            ) = 0
            AND TABLE_NAME NOT in (select tablename from @@DiscludeTables)
        )



    --GET THE PRIMARY KEY COLUMN FOR THIS TABLE IF ANY
    --************************************************
    DECLARE @PkColumnName NVARCHAR(128) = 
    (
        SELECT top 1 ccu.COLUMN_NAME
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS tc
        JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE ccu ON tc.CONSTRAINT_NAME = ccu.Constraint_name
        WHERE tc.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'Primary Key' AND '[dbo].['+TC.TABLE_NAME+']' = @TableName
    )

    --LOOP THROUGH ALL COLUMNS NOT IN DISCLUDE COLUMNS
    --************************************************
    SET @ColumnName = ''
    DECLARE @columns nvarchar(max) = ' '
    WHILE @ColumnName IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        SET @ColumnName = 
        (
            SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME))
            FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
            WHERE       TABLE_SCHEMA    = PARSENAME(@TableName, 2)
                AND TABLE_NAME  = PARSENAME(@TableName, 1)
                AND QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) > @ColumnName
                AND COLUMN_NAME NOT in (SELECT columnname FROM @@DiscludeColumns)
        )


        if @columnname != '['+@pkColumnName+']'
        BEGIN
            if @columns != ' '
            begin
                set @columns = @columns + ', '
            END 
            set @columns = @columns + 't.'+@ColumnName
        END 
    END


    if @columns != ' '
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @SQLSTRING varchar(max) =
                           '

                            ;WITH CTE_META AS (
                                SELECT [TableName] = ' + ''''+@tablename+''', t.*
                                , [Rank] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
                                    PARTITION BY ' + @columns + ' 
                                    ORDER BY ' + 't.['+@pkColumnName+']
                                ) FROM ' + @tablename + ' t
                            ) 
                            DELETE FROM ' + @tablename + '
                            WHERE ' + @pkColumnName + ' IN (SELECT cte.'+@pkColumnName+' FROM CTE_META cte WHERE cte.Rank > 1)

                            --SELECT cte.* 
                            --FROM CTE_META cte
                            --WHERE cte.RANK > 1
                            '
        SET @Output = @Output + @SQLSTRING

    END

END
--END OF LOOP THROUGH TABLES

--**************************
if @OUTPUT IS NOT NULL AND @OUTPUT != ''
BEGIN
    SET @OUTPUT = 
                'use [' + @DBName + ']

                ' + @Output
END 
PRINT @OUTPUT
```

Comment: Have you considered just using a couple of tables in dbo instead of comma separated strings? It would simplify the code a bit. Administrative code like this is why I don't allow application objects in dbo. Reserving the schema makes sure the tables you could be using here don't "get lost in the shuffle".

Comment: This script assumes that all tables to be checked have no more than one primary key column. Is that guaranteed?

Comment: Also, which (minimal) version of MSSQL are you running this on? At least since 2008 you could pass [table valued parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx) instead of strings which need to be split.

Answer (score 8):

You started out with all your keywords being capitalized and then you abandoned your capitalization haphazardly throughout the script, this makes it a little hard to read because your brain says that keywords are capitalized and then all of a sudden you see a `begin` and your brain says,

> "hold up a second, no that's a keyword, never mind"

make sure that all your keywords are capitalized.

Here is a good example

> ```
>     if @columnname != '['+@pkColumnName+']'
>     BEGIN
>         if @columns != ' '
>         begin
>             set @columns = @columns + ', '
>         END 
>         set @columns = @columns + 't.'+@ColumnName
>     END
> ```

This also brings up something else that can really go either way, but I will explain my reasoning.

Your if statements should be indented, and this is how I would have written it,

```
IF @columnname != '['+@pkColumnName+']'
    BEGIN
        IF @columns != ' '
            BEGIN
                SET @columns = @columns + ', '
            END 
        SET @columns = @columns + 't.'+@ColumnName
    END
```

I know that is a lot of indentation for an if statement nested inside of an if statement, but I always want to make certain I know exactly what my code is doing, especially when writing SQL Stored Procedures that are going to be creating `DELETE` scripts.

I may also consider doing it this way to save on indentation

```
IF @columnname != '['+@pkColumnName+']'
BEGIN
    IF @columns != ' '
    BEGIN
        SET @columns = @columns + ', '
    END 
    SET @columns = @columns + 't.'+@ColumnName
END
```

I also indent the `SELECT` statements a little differently as well, and if I recall correctly, I think that many other SQL writers do it the same way that I do.

I would take this,

> ```
> SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME))
> FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
> WHERE       TABLE_SCHEMA    = PARSENAME(@TableName, 2)
>     AND TABLE_NAME  = PARSENAME(@TableName, 1)
>     AND QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) > @ColumnName
>     AND COLUMN_NAME NOT in (SELECT columnname FROM @@DiscludeColumns)
> ```

and indent everything after the `SELECT` like this,

```
SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME))
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = PARSENAME(@TableName, 2)
        AND TABLE_NAME = PARSENAME(@TableName, 1)
        AND QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) > @ColumnName
        AND COLUMN_NAME NOT IN (SELECT columnname 
                                    FROM @@DiscludeColumns)
```

---

And the last and most important thing that I could advise is that you put intentional commenting on the `DELETE` portion of the script and uncomment the `SELECT` portion of the rendered script, so that you always run a `SELECT` to see what you are planning on deleting, before you delete it.

Answer (score 5):

Aside from [Malachi's remarks](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/113994/53073) about capitalization of keywords and indentation of the code, I would add two points about variable naming:

- DON'T use variable names that start with `@@`, as they [are reserved for T-SQL functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4817434/1866347). This would now give a conflict between the parameter `@DiscludeTables` and the private table variable `@@DiscludeTables`, but I would suggest renaming the parameter to `@tablesToDisclude`.
- DO be consistent in capitalization of variable names. It is customary to use camelCasing, so change `@TableName` to `@tableName`, for instance. I would do the same for parameter names.

Some remarks about clean habits in SQL code:

- Use `nvarchar` when passing strings that are meant to [reference dabatase object names](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx). (Actually, it's a good idea to consider `nvarchar` for most values that will contain user-entered data which could easily need to include unicode characters, but that is outside the scope of this script).
- Use semicolons to end SQL statements. In your script you add a semicolon *before* the `WITH` for the CTE, because it *needs* to be separated from the statement preceding it. Always using semicolons keeps the code sane for [future versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710683/when-should-i-use-semicolons-in-sql-server).
- You don't need to check whether something `IS NULL` if you are also comparing it against something else. For instance: `if @OUTPUT IS NOT NULL AND @OUTPUT != ''` could be written `IF @OUTPUT != ''`, because if `@OUTPUT` is `NULL`, `@OUTPUT` compared to anything will always be false.
- `IS NOT IN` will only work for single column comparisons. When comparing two sets of data against each other, prefer to do a `LEFT JOIN` and check whether the right side `IS NULL`:

  ```
   LEFT JOIN @@DiscludeColumns dc
          ON dc.columnName = c.COLUMN_NAME
  WHERE dc.columnName IS NULL
  ```

  will yield the same result, and is extensible to more columns (if you would, for instance, exclude a column only if both column name AND table name are equal).
- Write a simple `JOIN` as in `INNER JOIN` explicitly. This may be a matter of taste, but once you go using multiple `LEFT` and `RIGHT JOIN`s, this makes the `INNER` stand out.

Now, on to specific things in this script. In the beginning of the stored procedure, you have some duplicate code. Splitting the incoming parameters into multiple values. It is not always easy to remove duplicated code in SQL, but in this case, a **table valued function** makes most sense:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_splitString] (@stringToSplit nvarchar(max), @separator nchar(1))
RETURNS @output TABLE (i int identity(0,1), s nvarchar(max))
AS
BEGIN
    WHILE CHARINDEX(@separator, @stringToSplit) > 0
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @pos INT;
        SELECT @pos = CHARINDEX(@separator, @stringToSplit);

        INSERT INTO @output(s) SELECT SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, 1, @pos-1);

        SELECT @stringToSplit = SUBSTRING(@stringToSplit, @pos+1, LEN(@stringToSplit)-@pos);
    END
    IF @stringToSplit != ''
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @output SELECT @stringToSplit;
    END
    RETURN
END
GO
```

This function will take two inputs, the `@stringToSplit`, which you already use, and the `@separator`, for which you'd just enter the `';'`. This function returns a table with two columns, namely `i`, which is an identity column, in case you would like to remember the order in which the strings were given, and `s`, the strings themselves. The rest of the function is actually quite unchanged from the code you used, except that it stores the results in `@output` instead of e.g. `@@DiscludeTables`. You would call it in the stored procedure as such:

```
INSERT @@DiscludeTables (tableName)
    SELECT s FROM [dbo].[fn_splitString] (@DiscludeTables, N';');
INSERT @@DiscludeColumns (columnName)
    SELECT s FROM [dbo].[fn_splitString] (@DiscludeColumns, N';');
```

---

The last thing I would advise you, is to **avoid loops if possible** in SQL code, and use set based operations such as queries with joins. SQL Server was made to do set based operations, and you should take advantage of that.

For instance, instead of querying the INFORMATION_SCHEMA for each table to get the name, then querying it again to get the primary key column (only one?) and then repeatedly querying it to get the names of all the columns that you don't want to ignore, consider a larger query that takes all that information for all tables at once:

```
DECLARE @COLUMN_INFORMATION TABLE (tableName sysname, columnName sysname, isPrimaryKey bit, primary key (tableName, columnName));

INSERT @COLUMN_INFORMATION (tableName, columnName, isPrimaryKey)
SELECT [tableName] = (QUOTENAME(t.TABLE_SCHEMA) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(t.TABLE_NAME))
     , [columnName] = c.COLUMN_NAME
     , [isPrimaryKey] = CASE WHEN tc.TABLE_NAME IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END 
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t
 INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
         ON c.TABLE_NAME = t.TABLE_NAME
        AND c.TABLE_SCHEMA = t.TABLE_SCHEMA
  LEFT JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS tc
      INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE ccu
              ON tc.CONSTRAINT_NAME = ccu.Constraint_name
         ON tc.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'Primary Key'
        AND tc.TABLE_NAME = t.TABLE_NAME
        AND tc.TABLE_SCHEMA = t.TABLE_SCHEMA
        AND c.COLUMN_NAME = ccu.COLUMN_NAME
  LEFT JOIN @@DiscludeTables dt
         ON dt.tableName = t.TABLE_NAME
  LEFT JOIN @@DiscludeColumns dc
         ON dc.columnName = c.COLUMN_NAME
 WHERE t.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
   AND OBJECTPROPERTY( OBJECT_ID( QUOTENAME(t.TABLE_SCHEMA) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(t.TABLE_NAME) ) , 'IsMSShipped' ) = 0
   AND dt.tableName IS NULL
   AND dc.columnName IS NULL;
```

(This is not the most usual indentation style for SQL, by the way, so ignore it if it's not your taste).

This will return a table containing all non-ignored table names, combined with all non-ignored (and non-primary-key) column names and a bit that says whether that column is a primary key.

Now we have all the information, we can group the information per table. We want only one script for each table, so we need to combine the column names, which is something that SQL does not yet know how to do (there is no `CONCAT` function that would work like a `MAX` or `SUM`). In T-SQL, we can use `FOR XML PATH` though, to [simulate that behavior](http://sqlperformance.com/2014/08/t-sql-queries/sql-server-grouped-concatenation):

```
DECLARE @GROUPED_COLUMN_INFORMATION TABLE (tableName sysname primary key, columns nvarchar(max), primaryColumns nvarchar(max), primaryColumnsCompare nvarchar(max));

INSERT @GROUPED_COLUMN_INFORMATION (tableName, columns, primaryColumns, primaryColumnsCompare)
   SELECT [tableName] = ci.tableName
        , [columns] =
              ( STUFF((SELECT N', t.' + columnName 
                         FROM @COLUMN_INFORMATION c2
                        WHERE ci.tableName = c2.tableName
                          AND c2.isPrimaryKey = 0
                          FOR XML PATH(N''), TYPE).value(N'.[1]', N'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, N'')
              )
        , [primaryColumns] =
              ( STUFF((SELECT N', t.' + columnName 
                        FROM @COLUMN_INFORMATION c2
                       WHERE ci.tableName = c2.tableName
                         AND c2.isPrimaryKey = 1
                         FOR XML PATH(N''), TYPE).value(N'.[1]', N'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, N'')
              )
        , [primaryColumnsCompare] =
              ( N'ON ' + STUFF((SELECT N' AND t.' + columnName + N' = cte.' + columnName
                                  FROM @COLUMN_INFORMATION c2
                                 WHERE ci.tableName = c2.tableName
                                   AND c2.isPrimaryKey = 1
                                   FOR XML PATH(N''), TYPE).value(N'.[1]', N'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 5, N'')
               )
     FROM @COLUMN_INFORMATION ci
    GROUP BY ci.tableName;
```

While grouping the information, we also prepare some of the strings that we need in the script to output. For instance, in `[columns]`, we combine all the column names from the `@COLUMN_INFORMATION` table that are not a primary key, and we join them with the text `', t.'`, so that they are separated by commas and show up as `t.columnName`. The `STUFF(nvarchar, first, last, N'')` function makes sure that positions `first` through `last` are replaced with the empty string (`N''`). This gets rid of the comma in the beginning.

In `[primaryColumnsCompare]`, all primary columns are listed twice, showing up as `AND t.primaryColumn = cte.primaryColumn`. `STUFF` removes the inital `' AND '` part for us.

Finally, now we have combined all information into a table with one entry per table to check, we generate the script:

```
SELECT @output = '';
SELECT @output += '
    ;WITH CTE_META AS (
          SELECT [TableName] = ' + ''''+ gci.[tablename] +''', t.*
               , [Rank] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
                              PARTITION BY ' + gci.[columns] + ' 
                              ORDER BY ' + gci.[primaryColumns] + '
                           ) FROM ' + gci.[tablename] + ' t
          ) 
          SELECT cte.*
          --DELETE t
            FROM ' + gci.[tablename] + ' t
           INNER JOIN CTE_META cte ' + gci.[primaryColumnsCompare] + '
           WHERE cte.Rank > 1;
    '
  FROM @GROUPED_COLUMN_INFORMATION gci;
IF @output != ''
BEGIN
    SELECT @output = 'USE [' + db_name() + ']' + @output;
    PRINT @output;
END
```

(In this case, I didn't bother with the `FOR XML PATH`, because we are summing up one single string. Although the behavior of `SELECT @output += '...'` is not guaranteed to work with future versions of SQL Server, so you may want to do an extra step to combine it using a `FOR XML PATH`.)

Also, the output script changed a bit: the `DELETE` is commented out in favor of the `SELECT` to verify which data you are deleting. And also here, the `IS IN` has been replaced by a simple `INNER JOIN`.